# React Carousel rotate on delay issue when setting state in parent component causing rerender?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

Hopefully, the title isn't too ambiguous, but I am struggling how to summarise my issue in just a few words.

What I am attempting to achieve is the one image with appear for 1.5 seconds, the opacity of image will go from 0.3 to 1 and a string of text "Completed" appears below the image, and will then rotate and move to the next image where it will have the same outcome, constantly looping through each image.

The issue is, it only seems to rotate once. It will update the styles and add the text below the image but fail to rotate.

I have a 3d carousel component that rotates the items within an array `logos` when a function is called `rotate()`.

```
const [rotateDeg, setRotateDeg] = useState(0);
const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

const rotate = () => {
   const maxIndex = logos.length - 1;
   const incrementIndex = currentIndex + 1;
   const newIndex = incrementIndex > maxIndex ? 0 : incrementIndex;
   setCurrentIndex(newIndex);
   setRotateDeg(rotateDeg - 360 / logos.length);
};

return (
    <Container>
      <Carousel ref={carousel} logosLength={logos.length} rotateDeg={rotateDeg}>
        {logos.map((item, index) => {
          const { key } = item;
          return (
            <Item
              key={key}
              index={index}
              logosLength={logos.length}
              currentIndex={currentIndex}
            >
              <LoadingSpinLogo
                item={item}
                delay={1500 * (index + 1)}
                rotate={() => rotate()}
                key={key}
                isCurrent={currentIndex === index}
              />
            </Item>
          );
        })}
      </Carousel>
    </Container>
  );
```

The component `LoadingSpinLogo` is where I seem to be having an issue.

I have tried to pass different dependencies into the `useEffect` callback but it seems to cause weird issues with the delay.

```
const LoadingSpinLogo = ({ item, rotate, delay, isCurrent }) => {
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(false);
  const [divStyle, setDivStyle] = useState({ opacity: 0.3 });

  const props = useSpring(divStyle);

  const customStyles = {
    height: "78px",
    width: "115px",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundPosition: "center center",
    display: "block",
    margin: "auto"
  };

  const updateCompleted = () => {
    setCompleted(true);
    setDivStyle({ opacity: 1, from: { opacity: 0.3 } });
    rotate();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
      updateCompleted();
    }, delay);
    return () => {
      // Clean up the subscription
      window.clearInterval(timeoutID);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <LoadingSpinContainer>
      <animated.div style={props}>
        <ImageServer png={item.url} customStyles={customStyles} />
      </animated.div>
      {completed ? "Completed" : null}
    </LoadingSpinContainer>
  );
};
```

Here is a [CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-grass-jf8qc?file=/src/LoadingSpinLogo.js) of my components.

Any idea where I am going wrong here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `[]` in your `useEffect` function seems to works fine for me

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
      updateCompleted();
    }, delay);
    return () => {
      // Clean up the subscription
      window.clearInterval(timeoutID);
    };
  }, );
```

Comment: That does cause the rotation to work, however, it doesn't update the opacity of the image or add `Completed` below the image.